# ScrollViewer how to scale scrolling?

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

While creating some sort of image manipulation program, i ran into a scaling problems. I'm using a canvas placed in a `ScrollViewer` as surface.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <Canvas Height="{Binding GridHeight}" Width="{Binding GridWidth}">
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform  ScaleX="{Binding ScaleX}" ScaleY="{Binding ScaleY}"/>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
    </Canvas>               
</ScrollViewer>
```

This appears to look like this, when my application starts im windowed mode:

[image]
But after resizing it to full window mode, the scroll bars disappear, but the scale of the surface stays the same:

[image] 
This works just as I want it to. But I don't want the scroll bars to disappear.
When i change `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` of my canvas, the scroll bars won't reappear even after the surface fills more than the whole `ScrollViewer`.

Is there a way to change the ScrollScale of a `ScrollViewer` object programmatically or some other solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your ScrollViewer is not aware about the changes that ScaleTransform does on the Canvas. What I did to fix the issue is added `Grid` control which will host `Canvas` control and I'm setting `Height` and `Width` of the `Grid` as `CanvasHeight * ScaleY` and `CanvasWidth * ScaleX` respectively that way you have specific dimensions assigned to a control and `ScrollViewer` will notice it.

I've created a demo application which will help you to understand the issue, BTW, the code I'm posting here is working as you expect it to work:

**ValueConverter.cs**

```
public class ValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double originalValue = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
        double multiplier = System.Convert.ToDouble(parameter);

        return originalValue * multiplier;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private double gridHeight = 500.0;
    public double GridHeight
    {
        get { return gridHeight; }
        private set { gridHeight = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(GridHeight))); }
    }


    private double gridWidth = 500.0;
    public double GridWidth
    {
        get { return gridWidth; }
        private set { gridWidth = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(GridWidth))); }
    }


    private int scaleX = 1;
    public int ScaleX
    {
        get { return scaleX; }
        set
        {
            if (value > 0)
            {
                var oldScaleX = scaleX;
                scaleX = value;
                GridWidth *= (double)scaleX / oldScaleX;
            }

            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ScaleX)));
        }
    }


    private int scaleY = 1;
    public int ScaleY
    {
        get { return scaleY; }
        set
        {
            if (value > 0)
            {
                var oldScaleY = scaleY;
                scaleY = value;
                GridHeight *= (double)scaleY / oldScaleY;
            }

            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ScaleY)));
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }

    private void btnScaleXIncrease_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((ViewModel)DataContext).ScaleX++;
    }

    private void btnScaleXDecrease_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((ViewModel)DataContext).ScaleX--;
    }

    private void btnScaleYIncrease_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((ViewModel)DataContext).ScaleY++;
    }

    private void btnScaleYDecrease_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((ViewModel)DataContext).ScaleY--;
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplicationTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:ValueConverter x:Key="ValueConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <GroupBox Header="Scale X" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="100">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Width="40" Click="btnScaleXIncrease_Click">+</Button>
                    <Button Width="40" Click="btnScaleXDecrease_Click">-</Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Header="Scale Y" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="100">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Width="40" Click="btnScaleYIncrease_Click">+</Button>
                    <Button Width="40" Click="btnScaleYDecrease_Click">-</Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </GroupBox>
            <StackPanel></StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>

        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <Grid Width="{Binding GridWidth, Mode=OneWay}" Height="{Binding GridHeight, Mode=OneWay}">
                <Canvas Height="{Binding GridHeight, Mode=OneTime}" Width="{Binding GridWidth, Mode=OneTime}"
                    Background="Gray">
                    <Ellipse Fill="Yellow" Height="500" Width="500" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Black"/>
                    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ScaleX}" ScaleY="{Binding ScaleY}"
                                    CenterX="{Binding GridWidth, Converter={StaticResource ValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=0.5, Mode=OneTime}"
                                    CenterY="{Binding GridHeight, Converter={StaticResource ValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=0.5, Mode=OneTime}" />
                    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                </Canvas>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `scrollviewer` has `HorizontalScrollBarVisibilityProperty` and `VerticalScrollBarVisibilityProperty`
You should be able to force these to `visible` in you xaml to always show.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.horizontalscrollbarvisibility?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Controls_ScrollViewer_HorizontalScrollBarVisibility 
and: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.verticalscrollbarvisibility?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Controls_ScrollViewer_VerticalScrollBarVisibility

For further reading.

Comment: Sorry I missed the property initializer in xaml and added these. I already had them in my implementation.